# Updating Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have  table in which when the points are dragged , the corresponding value in table gets updated.

But i have done it using switch statement and is getting  quite complex.

Is there a way i can achieve same using simple `jquery/Javascript` code.

Here is **[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5LmNrs/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can have a function like this:

```
function updater(yv,xv){
   var num = xv.match(/^\d+/);
   $('#b'+num).html(yv);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5LmNr/1/)

Comment: Would you please help me out in fiddle

Comment: When we click on Y axis column and enter value , the chart gets updated, even it is done using switch. Any help on it???

Comment: @Richa, yeah. I'm looking into it. Just a minute

Comment: glad to have helped you ;)